Export named 'ConfigType' not found in module when using with Bun.js
When using Bun with @nestjs/config I have problem while injecting config to module.
There is any way to using @nestjs/config with Bun?
import { ConfigType } from '@nestjs/config';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { forwardRef, Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    /**
     * Construct for inject services and repositories
     * @param usersRepository
     */
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(User)
        private usersRepository: Repository<User>,

        @Inject(profileConfig.KEY)
        private readonly profileConfiguration: ConfigType<typeof profileConfig>,
    ) {}
}

I tried to run with npm/Nodejs and everything work fine but didn't work with Bun.
Here is the output when using with Bun:
1 | (function (entry, fetcher)
    ^
SyntaxError: Export named 'ConfigType' not found in module 'path_to_project/node_modules/@nestjs/config/index.js'.
1 | (function (entry, fetcher)
    ^
SyntaxError: Export named 'ConfigType' not found in module 'path_to_project/node_modules/@nestjs/config/index.js'.

